# A binding can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I try to develop a `UserControl` look like a `TextBox` white two different changes.

1. First of all the new `TextBox` has to display a "PlaceholderText" if the `TextBox` text value is empty. My solution for this implementation includes a second `TextBox` white the "PlaceholderText" as simply Text Attribute. At last I changed the visibility an the focus to the other `TextBox`.
2. An when the Textbox ValidationResult Object return false they display a `TextBlock` white an "ErrorMessage"

They tow implementations are already working and existent. For my new `TextBox` I copied all the `TextBox` specific properties into my new control and passed them to the original `TextBox`.

Now I tried to bind the `Text` property from my new control to a DependencyPropery Object (in the ViewModel).

My implementation looks this:

Custom TextBox Text property

```
public string Text
{
    get => TbSource.Text;
    set => TbSource.Text = value;
}
```

ViewModel propdp

```
public static DependencyProperty PersonProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Person), typeof(Person), typeof(PersonViewModel));

public Person Person
{
    get => (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty);
    set => SetValue(PersonProperty, value);
}
```

And my view

```
<customControl:NiceTextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsPlaceholderAktive="True" PlaceholderText="Enter first name" ErrorMessage="The given first name isn't valid." Text="{Binding Person.Name}" />
```

Now in the implementation in the View I became follow message: [image]

Has anyone an idea how to fix it? I tried to change my Text property to a dependency property but then I can't pass the input and output from the TbSource.

Answer (score 2):

The `Text` property of your custom control - the target property - must be a dependency property for you to be able to bind to it like this in XAML:

```
<customControl:NiceTextBox ... Text="{Binding Person.Name}" />
```

But the `Person` property in the view model - the source property - shouldn't be defined as a dependency property.

So you have defined the dependency property in the wrong class. Only *target* properties must be defined as dependency property for you to be able to bind them to some source property.

A control inherits from a `DependencyObject` class where the `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods are defined but a view model generally doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Make your UserControl `Text` property as `DependencyProperty` and the property in `ViewModel` as a normal CLR property and bind it.

**UserControl**

```
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(NiceTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

**ViewModel**

`public Person Person { get; set; }`

**XAML**

```
<customControl:NiceTextBox ... Text="{Binding Person.Name}" />
```